# Is there any way to create APK, IPA in just one shot in IONIC just like Phonegap build?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I was working on an Ionic2 project, where my client is asking for installable mobile app files for 3-4 platforms together, I have seen in Cordova/PhoneGap if you upload any client-side based project wrapped in zip or RAR format and upload it in PhoneGap build, they immediately provide the installable/downloadable file for various platform in just one shot, as shown in this video link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOjoNEUFeVE&t=210s

I was wondering that is it possible in IONIC as well? because it is using the same Cordova for its framework development, Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do that using [**Ionic Package**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/package/).

> Ionic Pro’s Package feature makes it easy to build native app binaries
>   for iOS and Android in the cloud. Perfect for automating binary builds
>   and for developers using Windows that want to build iOS apps.